# Connecting JavaFX with Firebase

Tags: firebase, javafx

Is there any way for JavaFX (desktop) to work with Firebase.  I built this web app as well as mobile counter parts that both interact with firebase but have this desktop part in JavaFX.  After many searches, i can't seem to find anything solid.  Feel free mention any other tech required to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about JavaFX on Android via Gluons tech stack? Some more background info is needed to answer your question.

Comment: Desktop JavaFX.

Comment: At first reading, you can use your backend server (`node.js`) to communicate with the firebase services and provide a rest interface to them. Then design your API as you see fit.